# scrollIntoView takes me to the element than comes back to the same view

Tags: angular, typescript

*I am trying to write a method in angular 8 for search on table.*
I have a autocomplete search for a column in table, after the name is selected the user should be scrolled to the row of the selected item. Below is the method that is triggered on search.

```
search(event: string) {
let selectedData;
const tableElements = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('name-column'));
if(tableElements) {
  selectedData = tableElements.filter((ele)  => {
    if(ele.firstChild['innerText'] === event) return ele;
  });
  const td = this.renderer.parentNode(selectedData[0]);
  const tr = this.renderer.parentNode(td);
  tr.scrollIntoView();
 }
}
```

Problem: What is happening is the page scrolls to the tr but then comes back to the input field. Please help.

Answer (score -1):

Yes when you type again in the input field the browser focus on to the field like the same scroll into view way so the user knows what he is typing

You can make your input field have a fixed position or make your scrolling list have a width smaller than the height of the page and make it overflow auto

Height can be set using max height so that the size of the list doesn't go beyond that height and it just scroll from inside that div only